# OpenGL ES 2.0 Shaders -- which line is the error?

Tags: android, opengl-es

In android OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders, if you have an error, how do you find out which line of the shader your error is on?? I have some code like this:

```
public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);
        // add the source code to the shader and compile it
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

        final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

        if (compileStatus[0] != 1) { // 1 is normal output
            if (type == GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER) {
                System.out.println("vertex -- ");
            }
            else if (type == GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)  {
                System.out.println("fragment -- ");
            }
            System.out.println(type + " error " + compileStatus[0]);
            if (compileStatus[0] == GLES20.GL_TRUE) System.out.println("true");
        }

        return shader;
    }
```

It always says that my shaders have built right. Meanwhile I run this code later:

```
    System.out.println(GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(mProgramHandle));
```

And it says that I have an error. This is the error msg:

```
W/Adreno-ES20﹕ <core_glGetShaderiv:443>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

How do I find out which line is the offending one??!!

EDIT: I probably should have included this code. Here I use the load shader code. This GL shader set works on one device and not another.

```
private int prepGLShader() {

        int mProgramHandle = 0;
        mProgramHandle = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program

        String vertex = readTextFileFromRawResource(context, R.raw.vert_mask);
        String fragment = readTextFileFromRawResource(context, R.raw.frag_mask);

        mVertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertex);
        mFragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragment);

        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgramHandle, mVertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgramHandle, mFragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program

        GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, 0, "a_Position");
        GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, 1, "a_TexCoordinate");


        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgramHandle);



        return mProgramHandle;
    }
```

Comment: Are you shure that mProgramHandle points to a valid shader handle? For me it looks like as if glGetShaderInfoLog produces the GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Comment: If the variable naming is any indication, `mProgramHandle` is most likely a program handle, not a shader handle.

Comment: so you're saying I should put mVertexShader or mFragmentShader in the glGetShaderInfoLog command? If I do this there's no error message of any sort.

Comment: I edited my original post a little to include some more code that uses the shader loader. As is my continuing problem, I can get this code to work on one device, but when I test it on any other device, it doesn't work. The image I'm looking for seems to flash on the screen when I start the app on one of the 'troubled' devices. The error log is not helpful enough it seems. Any suggestions would be welcome I think.